# Issue with Query Doctrine and zend 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have doctrine and zend 2 I do this script

```
$dql = $entityManager->createQuery('SELECT g FROM \Synchro\Entity\Geographicalarea g WHERE (g.namegeographicalarea = :namegeographicalarea ) AND g.codegeo = :codegeo');


            $dql->setParameters(array(
                    'namegeographicalarea' => '$this->GetSQLValueString($nameGeographicalArea,"text")',
                    'codegeo' => '$this->GetSQLValueString($nameGeographicalArea,"text")',

            ));
            $checkgeographicalarea = $query->getResult();
```

I `var_dumped` (`$checkgeographicalarea`) It was empty. I don't know why because I have the data

how can I resolved that ?

Comment: any feed back of your issue, is it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use Doctrine 2 and since your query was very simple i advise you to use this

```
$entityManager->getRepository('Synchro\Entity\Geographicalarea')->findBy(array(
'namegeographicalarea' => $nameGeographicalArea,
'codegeo' => $nameGeographicalArea,
));
```

Plus you have declared `'$this->GetSQLValueString($nameGeographicalArea,"text")',` with simple quotes wich is not working in PHP. and your `codego = $nameGeographicalArea`is this what you want ?

You have many issues here.